# Create docker image of Postgres with data

Tags: postgresql, docker

I would like to know if is possible to create a docker image of Postgres with information. I have the sql script with the inserts and so on.

The situatation is that this is intended to be a docker image for my developer to test, they should only pull and run the image. Is that possible? I checked in google but I didn't see anything similar or with solution

Comment: Look at docker commit. But one thing you need to take care is of proper stopping of applications before committing. Usually, if applications are not stopped properly it might create conflicts such port already occupied or pid file already found when you run commited image..

Answer (score 0):

The regular way to store (permanent) data for use in containers is through [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), however your use case is having an explicit image that's tagged in order to support completely reproducible testing.

For this you can use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit) to capture the data changes:

1. Run the base postgresql image
2. Import the data
3. Commit the changes as a new image + tag

In order to make these steps even more reproducible, use a Dockerfile to do the importing of the data and build the data-filled image.